# Generating and updating table with AngularJS conditioned on tag value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and couldn't find an answer to this scenario.

Basically, I'm trying to generate a table with n number of tbody's (actually. rows, but using tbody because the repeater works best with the tbody using angularjs 1.0.7).

Every row is generated based on the number of items I have.

Initially when the page loads, there are no rows/tbody's. I will be connecting to a backend through websocket and getting data pushed. For each push, I would like to add a row/tbody if a row/tbody having the same key does not already exist, with the key coming from the backend.  If the key does exist, I would like the existing table row/tbody to be updated.

To make it more concrete, here is some code that I'm using:

```
            <tbody ng-repeat="quote in model.messages.message">             
                <tr>                                                                            
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="bottom" colspan="5"><font size="2">{{quote.value1}}</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right"><font size="2">{{quote.value2}}</font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right"><font size="2">{{quote.value3}}</font></td>
                </tr>                               
            </tbody></table>
```

with the "key" here being quote.value1.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the structure of your data that is returned from the server. Instead of quote.value1 etc why not make an array of values so your JSON looks like this:

Lets say that modal.messages =

```
   [{
      "id":1, 
      "values":
          [{"vid":1, "m":"This is a message value"},
            {"vid":2, "m":"THis is a second message"}]}, 
    {"id":2, "values":[...]}, ...]
```

Then each message has a values array.

So you can use ng-repeat over the values like this:

```
     <tbody ng-repeat="quote in model.messages">             
            <tr ng-repeat ="message in quote.values">
               <td >{{message.m}}</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
```

Now the retrieved values can be added to the appropriate area of the data and the view will be updated  correctly.

In your controller you push the new data to the array or update the existing value. Lets say that you receive data like this:

```
     data = {"vid":3, "m": "Another great message from the server"};
```

You job in the controller is to determine if this is a new message or an update to an existing one. A new one is easy:

```
     your_array.push(data);
```

will simply append it to the array and the view gets updated. I can show you how I do something similar but without using websockets.

```
    $scope.getUpdateData = function(quote){
      $http.post('YOUR_SERVER_URL')
        .success(function (data) {
         quote.values.push(data); //if it is new 
         //check if the id exist and simply replace otherwise.
       });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in terms of my scenario? The server pushes only a single quote at a time but my table might contain ten quotes already. I wouldn't want to destroy the existing table, just update if the quote is already displayed or create a new td if the quote is new. The JSON would look like this: quote:  { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3}.

Comment: Yes I can change the JSON. But the backend would still only send me one quote per push.

Comment: That's fine. As long as the quotes are in an array then it shouldn't matter. You just need to update the array with the pushed quote. I'll update the answer a bit.